# Rcrawler scrape does not yield pages

Tags: r, web-scraping, rcrawler

I'm using Rcrawler to extract the infobox of Wikipedia pages. I have a list of musicians and I'd like to extract their name, DOB, date of death, instruments, labels, etc.   Then I'd like to create a dataframe of all artists in the list as rows and the data stored as columns/vectors.

The code below throws no errors but I don't get any results either.  The xpath used in the code is effective when I use `rvest` on its own.

What is wrong with my code?

```
library(Rcrawler)
jazzlist<-c("Art Pepper","Horace Silver","Art Blakey","Philly Joe Jones")

Rcrawler(Website = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search/", no_cores = 4, no_conn = 4, 
     KeywordsFilter = jazzlist,
     ExtractXpathPat = c("//th","//tr[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 5) and parent::*)]//td",
                         "//tr[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 6) and parent::*)]//td"),
     PatternsNames = c("artist", "dob", "dod"), 
     ManyPerPattern = TRUE, MaxDepth=1 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I suspect you are thinking that Rcrawler package works differently from what it does. You may be confusing scraping with crawling.

Rcrawler simply starts from a given page and crawls *any* link out from that page. You can narrow down the paths using URL filters, or Keyword Filters as you have done, but it will still need to reach those pages via a crawling process. It doesn't run a search.

The fact you've started from a Wikipedia search page suggests you might be expecting it to run searches on the terms you've specified in `jazzlist`, but it won't do this. It will simply follow all links out from the Wikipedia search page, e.g. 'Main Pages', 'Content', 'Featured Content' from the left sidebar, and it may or may not eventually hit upon one of the terms you've used, in which case it will scrape data according to your xpath parameters.

The terms you've specified are going to be very rare, so while it will probably find them eventually via article cross-links from, say, 'Featured Pages', it will take an extremely long time.

**What I think you want instead** is to not use Rcrawler at all, but to call `rvest` functions from within a loop on your search terms. You just need to append the terms to the search URL you mentioned, and replace space with underscore:

```
library(rvest)
target_pages = paste0('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search/', gsub(" ", "_", jazzlist))

for (url in target_pages){
    webpage = read_html(url)
    # do whatever else you want here with rvest functions 
}
```

***Edit: Added solution below with OP's exact code for his specific case, as per his comment***

```
library(rvest)
target_pages = paste0('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search/', gsub(" ", "_", jazzlist))

for (url in target_pages){
    webpage = read_html(url)
    info<-webpage %>% html_nodes(xpath='//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "plainlist", " " ))]') %>% html_text() temp<-data.frame(info, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) data = rbind(data,temp) 
}
```

Comment: I added the following after the #do whatever else comment:  `info<-webpage %>% html_nodes(xpath='//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "plainlist", " " ))]') %>%
                html_text() 
        temp<-data.frame(info, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        data = rbind(data,temp)`   This worked and create a dataframe with character data ready for parsing with regex.

Comment: @Ben glad to hear it worked, could you please also mark the answer as correct in that case.

Comment: Sure @Mike-s  Just wondered if the protocol is to add my additional code to your original answer? :)  What's best?

Comment: @Ben sure, I've added it to the answer

Answer (score 3):

#### Scrape DATA from a specific list of wikipedia URLs

If you want to scrape a specific list of URLs with common patterns then use ContentScraper function:

```
library(Rcrawler)
jazzlist<-c("Art Pepper","Horace Silver","Art Blakey","Philly Joe Jones")
target_pages = paste0('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search/', gsub(" ", "_", jazzlist))
DATA<-ContentScraper(Url = target_pages , 
                     XpathPatterns = c("//th","//tr[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 5) and parent::*)]//td","//tr[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 6) and parent::*)]//td"),
                     PatternsName = c("artist", "dob", "dod"),
                     asDataFrame = TRUE)
View(DATA)
```

[image: Scrape list of wikipedia URLS]

#### Crawl and scrape data from wikipedia list of links

with a little effort i found a list of hard bop musicians in wikipedia, which I think you will be interested in scraping all those artists data; in this case, we will use Rcrawler function to gather and parse all those pages automatically.

```
Rcrawler(Website = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hard_bop_musicians" ,
         no_cores = 4, no_conn = 4, MaxDepth = 1, 
         ExtractXpathPat = c("//th","//tr[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 5) and parent::*)]//td","//tr[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 6) and parent::*)]//td"),
         PatternsNames = c("artist", "dob", "dod"),
         crawlZoneXPath = "//*[@class='mw-parser-output']")
#transform data into dataframe
 df<-data.frame(do.call("rbind", DATA))
```

- MaxDepth = 1 : Crawl only links in the start page
- crawlZoneXPath : Crawl only links in the body of the page ( the list of artists)
- ExtractXpathPat : XPath patterns of data to be extracted

[image: crawl wikipedia webpages]

Rcrawler creator

Comment: For `MaxDepth`, do you mean it only would crawl the first page of a search, eg, if you searched something in google and there are only ten results per page, or does it crawl all of the pages? Apologies if that's confusing